# GPRS SIM900 and GPS NEO-6M don't work together

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, communication, gps, command-line

I'm trying to get GPS coordinates and send them to my API through the GPRS SIM900 and GPS NEO-6M shields.

In `setup()`, I first start the GPRS shield and call the function that connects to the internet. Then in `loop()`, I start to capture GPS coordinates and finally I send to my API, but my code doesn't work with this logic. I'd like to connect once and get GPS coordinates and send them to the API many times making a tracking.

The app stops if I run the code. `connectToInternet()` in `setup()` and `getGpsPosition()` in `loop()`. The SIM900 shield connects but the NEO6-M shield does not display the coordinates. The GPS only captures the coordinates if I do not connect to the internet.

Could someone help me? Following is my code and printout of the response to AT commands.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <inetGSM.h>

static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 3;
InetGSM inet;
TinyGPSPlus gps;
SoftwareSerial serialGps(RXPin, TXPin);
char msg[50];
boolean started = false;
const char* dataCoord = "";

void setup() {
  // Serial connection.
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Serial.print(F("------------------------------------------------- \r\n"));
  Serial.println(F("Starting App Tracking Arduino"));
  Serial.print(F("------------------------------------------------- \r\n"));
  // Turn on GPRS
  powerUpGprs();
  // Start configuration of shield SIM900 with baudrate.
  if (gsm.begin(2400)) {
    Serial.println(F("\nstatus=READY"));
    started = true;
  } else Serial.println(F("\nstatus=IDLE"));
  if (started)
    connectToInternet();
  // Start configuration of shield GPS NEO-6M with baudrate.
  serialGps.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // This sketch displays information every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.
  while (serialGps.available() > 0)
    if (gps.encode(serialGps.read())) getGpsPosition();
}

/**
  Power up
*/
void powerUpGprs() {
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  Serial.println(F("\nPower Up SIM900!"));
}

/**
  Connect to Internet via GSM
*/
void connectToInternet() {
  Serial.print(F("\r\n"));
  Serial.print(F("------------------------------------------------- \r\n"));
  Serial.print(F(" CONNECT TO INTERNET \r\n"));
  Serial.print(F("------------------------------------------------- \r\n"));
  //GPRS attach, put in order APN, username and password.
  if (inet.attachGPRS("zap.vivo.com.br", "vivo", "vivo"))
    Serial.println(F("status=ATTACHED"));
  else
    Serial.println(F("status=ERROR"));
  delay(1000);
  //Read IP address.
  gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CIFSR");
}


/**
  Get GPS position
*/
void getGpsPosition() {
  Serial.print(F("\r\n\r\n"));
  Serial.print(F("------------------------------------------------- \r\n"));
  Serial.print(F(" GET POSITON \r\n"));
  Serial.print(F("------------------------------------------------- \r\n"));
  // geolocation
  TinyGPSDate &d = gps.date;
  TinyGPSTime &t = gps.time;
  char* timestamp;
  if (!d.isValid()) {
    timestamp = "00/00/0000 00:00:00";
  } else {
    char sz[32];
    sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
      d.day(), d.month(), d.year(),
      t.hour(), t.minute(), t.second());
    timestamp = sz;
  }
  String position = String("");
  position.concat(String("timestamp=") + String(timestamp));
  position.concat(String("&latitude=") + String(gps.location.lat(), 6));
  position.concat(String("&longitude=") + String(gps.location.lng(), 6));
  position.concat(String("&altitude=") + String(gps.altitude.meters()));
  position.concat(String("&speed=") + String(gps.speed.kmph()));
  Serial.println(dataCoord);
  send2Api();
}

/**
  Send To API, The function inet.httpPOST(),
  this is submit method POST via http request
*/
void send2Api() {
  Serial.print(F("\r\n\r\n"));
  Serial.print(F("------------------------------------------------- \r\n"));
  Serial.print(F(" SEND TO API\r\n"));
  Serial.print(F("------------------------------------------------- \r\n"));
  // Read until serial buffer is emapty.
  gsm.WhileSimpleRead();
  // TCP Client HTTP, send a POST request to the server and save the reply.
  int numdata = inet.httpPOST("api.myapp.com.br", 80, "/geolocations ", dataCoord, msg, 100);
  // Print the results.
  Serial.print(F("\nNumber of data received: "));
  Serial.println(numdata);
  Serial.print(F("\nData received: "));
  Serial.println(msg);
};
```

If I connect to internet the GPS does not display the coordinates.

[image: Run app with connectToInternet() and getGpsPosition]

But if I don't connect to internet the GPS displays the coordinates.

[image: connectToInternet() function omitted]

Comment: I solved.... my solution https://github.com/robsonfagundes/Arduino-GprsSIM900andGpsNEO-6M

I made example to help other developers who are facing the same problem or a similar problem with Gprs SIM900 and Gps NEO-6M working together.

Comment: Good day sir. It is possible that when send a location to mobile phone there's a link to google map so that i can find where's the vehicle.? What is the code for that?

Comment: @Cymon here https://github.com/robsonfagundes/arduino-gprs-sim-900-gps-neo-6m

Comment: and... here https://www.cooking-hacks.com/projects/arduino-realtime-gps-gprs-vehicle-tracking

Answer (score 2):

You are using 2 SoftwareSerial instances and you're losing bytes when you aren't listening to the other port. Also your `inetGSM` library uses pins 3 for RX with the SIM900 and in your Arduino sketch, pin 3 is also the Arduino TX pin to the GPS module. Therefore, anything sent by the Arduino over pin 3 is received by both modules. Confusion.

- Use the GPS module with another pair of pins, maybe, 7 for RX and 8 for TX. Connect the GPS TX to 7 and its RX to 8.
- Try adding: `gsm._cell.listen();` right before this line:

  `// Read until serial buffer is empty.
  gsm.WhileSimpleRead();`
- Also add `serialGps.listen();` right before this line:

  `// Print the results.
  Serial.print(F("\nNumber of data received: "));`

Refer to this [answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22633/solved-dbno-resp-using-inet-httppost-on-loop/22637#22637) for more details.

Comment: @RobsonFagundes Its in the library u're using. Have you tried it yet? Did it compile?

Comment: @RobsonFagundes what error did you get? Does everything work now? Any improvements?

Comment: @RobsonFagundes provide a link to your library. Are there any improvements?

Comment: here it is [Library SIMCom SIM900](http://www.open-electronics.org/arduino-gsm-shield/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37403/discussion-between-robson-fagundes-and-tisteandii).